# How to retrieve the Printed information container of PIV card?

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, pcsc

How to retrieve the values printed on the back of the PIV card. Any APDU command or PCSC method?

Comment: have you checked any available documentation for the device? Maybe it shows what information the device does and does not electronically which you can retrieve?

Comment: I don't know the product in question but that would imply to me that it's not possible, or at least not supposed. Do they have technical support you can email or something? If not you'll have to wait and see if anyone here has ever used the specific item and tried to do it, which sounds like a long shot...

Answer (score 1):

Printed Information is PIN protected object in PIV standard. you have to

1. send VERIFY command to authenticate yourself as cardholder
2. send GET DATA command for Printed information ID
3. send Get Respone command (if information length exceed from 255)

for More Information read this document:
http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-73-4.pdf

Good Luck